# What is the use of typedef here?

Tags: c++, c, char, function-pointers, typedef

I am having difficulty to figure out what is the use `typedef` here-

```
typedef char TYPE_SSOSettingError;
typedef void (*ans_executeDomainRegistration) (TYPE_SSOSettingError);
```

From the first line I understand that `TYPE_SSOSettingError` is defined as `char`.

From the next line I can figure out that `ans_executeDomainRegistration`is a pointer to a function which is having return type of `void` and takes parameter of type `char` which in this situation is `TYPE_SSOSettingError`

Then what is the use of `typedef` in the last line?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What is the use of any typedef? Also, pick a language.

Comment: Maybe you should ask yourself: What is the use of the typedef in the first line? The answer does not really differ for the second line...

Comment: before you play with function pointers in C++, give this a read: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Comment: Are you going to pick a language? There are differences between C and C++ WRT `typedef`, so a complete answer would depend on the language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `typedef` is, as you noted, a pointer to a function. So it can be used to declare said pointer to said function and then bind it to an actual pointer to a function with said signature and then called as desired.

```
typedef char TYPE_SSOSettingError;
typedef void (*ans_executeDomainRegistration) (TYPE_SSOSettingError);
// ...
void somefunc(TYPE_SSOSettingError);
// ...
ans_executeDomainRegistration ptr = &somefunc;
```

The typical use case for this is with a callback function of some sort. It is used in the standard library for setting the terminate function etc. [`std::set_terminate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/set_terminate), with the [terminate handler `typedef`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate_handler).

```
typedef void (*terminate_handler)();
std::terminate_handler set_terminate( std::terminate_handler f );
```

---

In more general terms, use of the [`typedef`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) (and type aliases [`using`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef)) provides a technique to offer a better abstraction.

```
void (*ptr) (char) = &somefunc; // 1
ans_executeDomainRegistration ptr = &somefunc; // 2
```

Your case in point, it is unclear in line 1 what `ptr` will be used for, line 2 offers clearer intent, the `ptr` will be used as a function call for the execution of a domain registration and that function accepts an SSO settings error.

It is a technique to make the code easier to read, better, terse, or more succinct in order to express the concepts in the code (for some definition of easier, better etc.). Use them well; when not used well, they can also make the code more obscure, and harder to read and understand.

Answer (score 4):

To make more clear declarations like this:

```
int register_callback(void (*execute) (TYPE_SSOSettingError));
```

vs

```
int register_callback(ans_executeDomainRegistration* execute));
```

Also, to make it clear what a function pointer should be.

Answer (score 3):

You are right this is a typedef of a function pointer with return value `void` and parameter `TYPE_SSOSettingError`.

The `typedef` can be used to increase the readability of your code when
using a function pointer.

#### Function pointer declarations

For example declaring a function pointer `fct_ptr1` and `fct_ptr2` which are exactly the same:

```
// Type definition:
typedef void (*ans_executeDomainRegistration) (TYPE_SSOSettingError);

// Declarations:
ans_executeDomainRegistration fct_ptr1 = foo;    // With typedef
void (*fct_ptr2) (TYPE_SSOSettingError) = foo;   // Without typedef
```

#### Function declarations

Also if you have any function with a function pointer as parameter:

```
// Write:
void SomeFct(ans_executeDomainRegistration param) {...}        // With typedef
// Instead of:
void SomeOtherFct(void (*param)(TYPE_SSOSettingError)) {...}   // Without typedef
```

#### Conclusion

So as a result of using the `typedef` you see it is more familiar to
declare pointers or functions if you have declared a type for the function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef void (*ans_executeDomainRegistration) (TYPE_SSOSettingError);
```

typedefs a function pointer to a function of type `void(char)`.

Example:

```
void foo(char) {
  ...
}

int main() {
  ans_executeDomainRegistration f = &foo;

  f('a');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you've known about `typedef`, and you're asking about why to use defined `typedef` at 2nd `typedef`.

> Then what is the use of typedef in the last line.

It's guaranteed that if `TYPE_SSOSettingError` gets changed, the parameter's type of `ans_executeDomainRegistration` will get changed too.

Answer (score 2):

The second `typedef` makes it so you have a defined type for later use.

Here an example to contrast a use with and without `typedef`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char TYPE_SSOSettingError;
typedef void(*ans_executeDomainRegistration) (TYPE_SSOSettingError);

void myprint(TYPE_SSOSettingError c)
{
    printf("%c\n", c);
}

int main()
{
    ans_executeDomainRegistration with_typedef = myprint;
    void(*without_typedef) (TYPE_SSOSettingError) = myprint;

    with_typedef('w');
    without_typedef('o');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of a function which returns a function pointer of type `ans_executeDomainRegistration`.

Imagine something like:

```
ans_executeDomainRegistration getDomainRegistrationFunction(enum DomainType d)
{
  return global_ans_executeDomainRegistration[getDomainindex(d)];
}
```

which is called like:

```
(*getDomain(MY_DOMAIN))(varSSOSettingError);
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++ 11 you can use an alias declaration instead of the typedef that looks more clear.

For example

```
using ans_executeDomainRegistration = void ( * )( TYPE_SSOSettingError );
```

From this declaration it is seen that `ans_executeDomainRegistration` is a name for type `void ( * )( TYPE_SSOSettingError )`. That is this name denotes the type of pointer to function with one parameter and return type `void`.

So instead of writing in the program for example like

```
typedef char TYPE_SSOSettingError;
void myFunc( TYPE_SSOSettingError );

//...
void (*myFuncPtr1) (TYPE_SSOSettingError) = myFunc;
void (*myFuncPtr2) (TYPE_SSOSettingError) = myFunc;
```

you can write

```
ans_executeDomainRegistration myFuncPtr1 = myFunc;
ans_executeDomainRegistration myFuncPtr2 = myFunc;
```